# XNA - Reconnecting Content Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, xna, xna-4.0

I'm working with XNA 4 in VS2010. Recently a crash corrupted a .contentproj file of mine. So I deleted the content project inside VS, created a new one and repopulated it with the contents of the old one. However the new content project did not properly hook up to the rest of the program, whenever I build the program its contents aren't translated to .xnb-s and placed inside the content folder of the game as when I built the program with the original content project.

I'm sure I'm missing a step in reconnecting the new content project, I just can't seem to be able to find out what that step is. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work. More a workaround than a solution, I created a new VS solution, imported everything other than the content project from the old one and used the content project that came with the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the properties of the imported files in Visual Studio and check they are correct. Check the Build Action specifically. It should be set to Compile.